# Validation Exception in Business LayerConstraintViolation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, localization

I'm trying to use a validation-exception on the presentation layer in spring mvc to show to the user. I'd like the ConstraintViolation information as objects. As much as I understand it, the MessageSourceAware is not the right thing for me.

I would like to have the propertyPath of the ConstraintViolation localized. Does spring support me there?